# How to change the graphical attributes of a point in an Excel sunburst chart through Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, charts, attributes, apache-poi

I have a requirement to color the different data points in an Excel sunburst chart programatically. By default, Excel creates the chart looking like this.
[image]

I need to be able to make something like this.
[image]

I've been able to load the chart and series, what I have not been able to work out is how to get to each of the points and change the fill color, and is that even possible.

The data to create this chart is :

```
Level 1,Level 2,Level 3,Series 1
A,A.a,A.a.1,5
A,A.a,A.a.2,5
A,A.b,A.b.1,5
A,A.b,A.b.2,5
B,B.a,B.a.1,5
B,B.a,B.a.2,5
B,B.b,B.b.1,5
B,B.b,B.b.2,5
C,C.a,C.a.1,5
C,C.a,C.a.2,5
C,C.b,C.b.1,5
C,C.b,C.b.2,5
```

My code so far

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

public class Format {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            XSSFWorkbook xwb = new XSSFWorkbook("ChartExample.xlsx");
            XSSFSheet sheet = xwb.getSheetAt(0);
            System.out.println("Loaded sheet is " + sheet.getSheetName());
            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
            List <XSSFChart> charts = drawing.getCharts();
            System.out.println("No of Charts " + charts.size());
            XSSFChart chart = charts.get(0);
            List<XDDFChartData> series = chart.getChartSeries();
            System.out.println("No of Data Series " + series.size());
            XDDFChartData data = series.get(0);
            // How do I now get to the data points and then set the fill color for that point?
            xwb.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I now get to the say Point C.b.1 and set it's fill color to red?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You even will not get the sunburst chart using `List <XSSFChart> charts = drawing.getCharts();`. A sunburst chart is not a `XSSFChart`. `XSSFChart` is of type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml` while sunburst chart is of type `application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml`. So getting the sunburst chart `XML` will only be possible very low level by parsing the `XML` directly.

Comment: I went and delved into the xml directly and Excel only stores exceptions to the default sunburst scheme. If you manually change the fill color on one of the chart elements, that is added to the chart xml. To color up my chart, I would have to add all my own exceptions to the xml - decided it was all getting a bit too hard. Found this library [link](https://github.com/HanSolo/SunburstChart)  which works well and I have successfully gone down that route.

Comment: And how will you get the JavaFX sunburst chart component into Excel then? Or was creating an Excel chart not the goal at all?

Comment: My primary goal was to get a custom sunburst any way I could. The preferred solution is through Excel which is now working with the code provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is really to modify an `Excel` sunburst chart, then getting the sunburst chart XML will only be possible very low level by parsing the XML directly.

You even will not get the sunburst chart using `List <XSSFChart> charts = drawing.getCharts();`. A sunburst chart is not a `XSSFChart`. `XSSFChart` is of type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml` while sunburst chart is of type `application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml`. This is because the sunburst chart is an extended chart type which is not available in versions of Office Open XML up to year 2007. But those old versions of Office Open XML is what `apache poi` is developed on.

But we can using at least parts of `apache poi` and must programming the `XSSFChartEx` class instead the `XSSFChart` our own then. Unfortunately also a class `XSSFChartExRelation` is needed because such an relation class of course also not exists already.

Example:

Excel source:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLRelation;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class FormatSunBurstChart {

 private static void setDataPointColor(XmlObject series, int number, String colorHex) {
  XmlCursor cursor = series.newCursor();
  cursor.toLastChild();
  cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex", "dataPt", "cx"));
  cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("idx", "" + number);
  cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex", "spPr", "cx"));
  cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "solidFill", "a"));
  cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "srgbClr", "a"));
  cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("val", colorHex);

  cursor.dispose();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("ChartExample.xlsx"));
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   System.out.println("Loaded sheet is " + sheet.getSheetName());
   XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
   if (drawing != null) {
    for (POIXMLDocumentPart dpart : drawing.getRelations()) {
     PackagePart ppart = dpart.getPackagePart();
     if ("application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml".equals(ppart.getContentType())) {
      XSSFChartEx xssfChartEx = new XSSFChartEx(ppart);
      String rId = drawing.getRelationId(dpart);
      drawing.addRelation(
       rId, 
       new XSSFChartExRelation(
        "application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2014/relationships/chartEx",
        "/xl/charts/chartEx#.xml"),
       xssfChartEx
      );
      XmlObject series = xssfChartEx.getSeries(0);
      setDataPointColor(series, 1, "FF0000");
      setDataPointColor(series, 2, "FFFF00");
      setDataPointColor(series, 3, "00FF00");
      setDataPointColor(series, 14, "FFFF00");
      setDataPointColor(series, 16, "00FF00");
      setDataPointColor(series, 18, "00FF00");
      setDataPointColor(series, 19, "FF0000");
      setDataPointColor(series, 20, "00FF00");
System.out.println(series);
     }
    }
   }
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ChartExampleChanged.xlsx");
   workbook.write(out);
   workbook.close();
   out.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 private static class XSSFChartEx extends POIXMLDocumentPart {

  private XmlObject chartExXmlObject;

  private XSSFChartEx(PackagePart part) throws Exception {
   super(part);
   chartExXmlObject = XmlObject.Factory.parse(part.getInputStream());
  }

  private XmlObject getChartExXmlObject() {
   return chartExXmlObject;
  }

  private XmlObject getSeries(int number) {
   XmlObject[] result = chartExXmlObject.selectPath(
    "declare namespace cx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex' " +
    ".//cx:chart/cx:plotArea/cx:plotAreaRegion/cx:series"
   );
   return result[number];
  }

  @Override
  protected void commit() throws IOException {
   PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
   OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
   chartExXmlObject.save(out);
   out.close();
  }
 }

 private static class XSSFChartExRelation extends POIXMLRelation {
  private XSSFChartExRelation(String type, String rel, String defaultName) {
   super(type, rel, defaultName);
  }
 }
}
```

Note: `apache poi` version `4.0.0` is used here.

Excel result:

[image]

Comment: Next problem I need to solve is to adjust the text attributes of the data labels, in particular , the font size. What code do I need to add to setDataPointColor to change the font size for that data point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Andrew L: What do you want set? The text attributes of the data labels in general? Or the text attributes of separate single data labels? Nevertheless: This is not how SO works: Asking a question, getting a  answer and then asking other additional questions in comments. Please ask a separate SO Question about this new problem. You might refer to this  question in your new question.