# How to set the text attributes of the individual data labels in an Excel Sunburst Chart through Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324851/how-to-change-the-graphical-attributes-of-a-point-in-an-excel-sunburst-chart-thr) a solution was provided to set the graphical attributes of the data points.

I now need to access the individual data point labels and change the text attributes as well. My priority is to adjust the font size, however, the ability to adjust other attributes (e.g. font, bold, italic, alignment, etc) as well would be useful. This method sets the data point fill colour. What needs to be added to set the font size of the data label for that data point?

```
private static void setDataPointColor(XmlObject series, int number, String colorHex) {
    XmlCursor cursor = series.newCursor();
    cursor.toLastChild();
    cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex", "dataPt", "cx"));
    cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("idx", "" + number);
    cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex", "spPr", "cx"));
    cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "solidFill", "a"));
    cursor.beginElement(new  Name("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "srgbClr", "a"));
    cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("val", colorHex);

    cursor.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told in the question already, this is related to [How to change the graphical attributes of a point in an Excel sunburst chart through Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324851/how-to-change-the-graphical-attributes-of-a-point-in-an-excel-sunburst-chart-thr/52464948#52464948). In my answer there was told already that sunburst chart is of type `application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml` and so cannot be a `XSSFChart`as this is of type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml`. My answer there also provides a method to nevertheless get the `XML` of the sunburst chart in read and write mode.

But of course if one needs changing the `XML` one must know about what the `XML` is about. One could read `Microsoft`s documentation starting with [2.24.3.11 CT_ChartSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-odrawxml/416e664f-c6f6-4ed9-914b-4eaaa20724dd). But my approach is the following:

The `*.xlsx` file is nothing else than a `ZIP` archive. So I create a simple sunburst chart using `Excel` and save this in a `*.xlsx` file. Then I unzip that  `*.xlsx` file and have a look at `/xl/charts/chartEx1.xml`. There I can see the `XML` used. Now I do additional formatting the sunburst chart using `Excel`, save and have a look at how the `XML` in `/xl/charts/chartEx1.xml` has changed. So I can determine the meaning of the used `XML`.

Using this approach I come to the conclusion that each single data label can be formatted using a `<cx:dataLabel idx="0">` where the `idx` is the same as the data point `idx`. The formatting is done in `<cx:txPr>` which contains paragraph `<a:p>` and text run `<a:r>` which is formatted then.

Knowing this, we come to following method:

```
...
 private static void setDataLabelFontSettings(XmlObject series, int number,
  int fontSizePt, boolean b, boolean i, String u, String strike, String typeface, String colorHex) {

  XmlObject[] xmlObjects = series.selectPath(
   "declare namespace cx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex' " +
   ".//cx:dataLabels");
  if (xmlObjects.length == 1) {
   XmlObject dataLabels = xmlObjects[0];
   XmlCursor cursor = dataLabels.newCursor();
   cursor.toLastChild();
   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex", "dataLabel", "cx"));
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("idx", "" + number);

   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex", "txPr", "cx"));

   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "p", "a"));

   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "r", "a"));

   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "t", "a"));
   cursor.toParent();
   cursor.setTextValue("dummy");

   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "rPr", "a"));
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("sz", "" + (fontSizePt * 100));
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("b", ((b)?"1":"0"));
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("i", ((i)?"1":"0"));
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("u", u);
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("strike", strike);
   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "latin", "a"));
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("typeface", typeface);
   cursor.toParent();
   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "solidFill", "a"));
   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "srgbClr", "a"));
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue("val", colorHex);

   cursor.toParent();
   cursor.toParent();
   cursor.toParent();
   cursor.toParent();
   cursor.toParent();
   cursor.beginElement(new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", "bodyPr", "a"));

   cursor.dispose();
  }
 }
...
```

which can be used in my code in the related Q/A linked above as follows:

```
...
      //setDataLabelFontSettings(XmlObject series, int number, int fontSizePt, boolean b, boolean i, 
      // String u, String strike, String typeface, String colorHex)
      setDataLabelFontSettings(series, 0, 14, false, true, "sng", "noStrike", "Calibri", "FFFFFF");
      setDataLabelFontSettings(series, 4, 12, false, true, "none", "sngStrike", "Calibri", "FFFFFF");
      setDataLabelFontSettings(series, 5, 8, false, true, "dbl", "noStrike", "Calibri", "FFFFFF");
      setDataLabelFontSettings(series, 6, 8, false, true, "none", "dblStrike", "Calibri", "FFFFFF");
...
```