# Updating Waterfall Chart with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using the Apache POI Java library (v4.1.1) to create wonderfull Word documents including Excel Charts. For the Excel Charts I use an Excel template and via the Apache POI library access the charts in the Word document via

```
List<XWPFChart> chartList = wordDoc.getCharts();
```

This is working fine for Bar / Column / Line etc. I can't get, however, the Waterfall chart via this method. So, I am wondering if anybody has got a solution for this? I see some options;

1. Waiting until it is supported by Apache POI
2. Creating another chart type as a template, access that chart via getCharts method and altering the chart type programmatically
3. Creating my own code for generating a waterfall chart

I am hoping somebody already has experience with the second or even third option?

Comment: `XWPFChart` is of type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml` while waterfall chart is of type `application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml`. This is because the waterfall chart is an extended chart type which is not available in versions of `Office Open XML` which `apache poi` provides. I don't believe `apache poi` will provide such extended charts in  near future since it not even provides all native charts until now.

Comment: So until now there only is the option to work on those chart types on very low level by changing the `XML` directly. I have shown this for a sunburst chart here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324851/how-to-change-the-graphical-attributes-of-a-point-in-an-excel-sunburst-chart-thr/52464948#52464948 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974045/how-to-set-the-text-attributes-of-the-individual-data-labels-in-an-excel-sunburs/54987897#54987897.

Comment: Hi Axel, thanks for your swift reply. I took a look at your answers related to the sunburst Excel chart. My problem is slightly different, I am using Word. In Word I currently can't access the waterfall chart, or what you mention, the charts of type ```vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml```, because of your reason. The tricky part is I now that I don't have a template chart to start altering like the example you shared with the sunburst chart. What would be the best way to generate such a chart in Word either via template of from scatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XWPFChart` is of type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml` while waterfall chart is of type `application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml`. This is because the waterfall chart is an extended chart type which is not available in versions of `Office Open XML` which `apache poi` provides. I don't believe `apache poi` will provide such extended charts in near future since it not even provides all native charts of type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml` until now.

So until now there only is the option to work on those chart types on very low level by changing the XML directly. I have shown this for a sunburst chart here [How to change the graphical attributes of a point in an Excel sunburst chart through Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324851/how-to-change-the-graphical-attributes-of-a-point-in-an-excel-sunburst-chart-thr/52464948#52464948) and here [How to set the text attributes of the individual data labels in an Excel Sunburst Chart through Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974045/how-to-set-the-text-attributes-of-the-individual-data-labels-in-an-excel-sunburs/54987897#54987897).

Following working draft provides a very basic class `XWPFChartEx` which up to now  only provides method `getChartExXmlObject` which returns the plain `XML` of the extended chart as a `XmlObject`. This `XML` could be programmatically changed using low level `XML` methods. Because `XWPFChartEx` extends `POIXMLDocumentPart`, it's `commit` method will write that changes into the new `Word` document then while `document.write(out)`. And it provides `getWorkbookPart` which returns the `PackagePart` of the `XSSFWorkbook` containing the chart's data. This workbook content also would mus be changed, if present.

The file `Waterfall_Chart.docx` must have at least one waterfall chart.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRelation;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLRelation;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;

public class WordGetWaterfallChart {

 static XWPFChartEx getFirstXWPFChartEx(XWPFDocument document) throws Exception {
  XWPFChartEx xwpfChartEx = null;
  for (POIXMLDocumentPart dpart : document.getRelations()) {
   PackagePart ppart = dpart.getPackagePart();
   if ("application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml".equals(ppart.getContentType())) {
    xwpfChartEx = new XWPFChartEx(dpart);
    String rId = document.getRelationId(dpart);
    document.addRelation(
     rId, 
     new XSSFChartExRelation(
      "application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml",
      "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2014/relationships/chartEx",
      "/word/charts/chartEx#.xml"),
      xwpfChartEx
    );
    return xwpfChartEx;
   }
  }
  return xwpfChartEx;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("Waterfall_Chart.docx"));

  XWPFChartEx waterfallChart = getFirstXWPFChartEx(document);
  System.out.println(waterfallChart.getChartExXmlObject());
  //TODO: change the XML

  System.out.println(waterfallChart.getWorkbookPart());
  if (waterfallChart.getWorkbookPart() != null) {
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(waterfallChart.getWorkbookPart().getInputStream());
   for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
    for (Row row : sheet) {
     for (Cell cell : row) {
      System.out.println(cell);
      //TODO: change the cell contents
     }
    }
   }
   OutputStream wbOut = waterfallChart.getWorkbookPart().getOutputStream();
   workbook.write(wbOut);
   wbOut.close();
   workbook.close();
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Waterfall_Chart_Changed.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }

 private static class XWPFChartEx extends POIXMLDocumentPart {

  private XmlObject chartExXmlObject;
  private PackagePart workbookPart;

  private XWPFChartEx(POIXMLDocumentPart dpart) throws Exception {
   super(dpart.getPackagePart());
   this.chartExXmlObject = XmlObject.Factory.parse(dpart.getPackagePart().getInputStream());
   for (POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart rpart : dpart.getRelationParts()) {
    if ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
         .equals(rpart.getDocumentPart().getPackagePart().getContentType())) {
     this.addRelation(
      rpart.getRelationship().getId(), 
      XWPFRelation.getInstance(rpart.getRelationship().getRelationshipType()),
      rpart.getDocumentPart()
     );
     this.workbookPart = rpart.getDocumentPart().getPackagePart();
    }
   }
  }

  private XmlObject getChartExXmlObject() {
   return this.chartExXmlObject;
  }

  private PackagePart getWorkbookPart() {
   return this.workbookPart;
  }

  @Override
  protected void commit() throws IOException {
   PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
   OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
   chartExXmlObject.save(out);
   out.close();
  }
 }

 private static class XSSFChartExRelation extends POIXMLRelation {
  private XSSFChartExRelation(String type, String rel, String defaultName) {
   super(type, rel, defaultName);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Axel, again, thanks a lot for the response. I was actually already going in another direction of accessing the Excel worksheet of the non-supported chart. This can be done and the data can also be altered. The sad thing I found is that even though the underlying data is changed, the chart is not directly refreshed... Clicking 'Edit Data' will refresh the chart, but that would be an annoying user experience. Do you have a workaround for that? If so I will stick to that approach. If not, I will try to implement the answer you just posted.

Comment: @Ivo Sturm: To change chart data both must always be changed, the `XML` of the `/word/charts/chartEx*.xml` as well as the `Excel` data in `/word/embeddings/*.xlsx`. See the both `//TODO` in my code example. If only one of both is changed, then `Word` does not show the updated chart.