# How to extract advanced chart info from Excel using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-charts

Is there a way to use Apache POI to extract the following information (preferably all the info):

1. title (including position + style)
2. axes (including position + style)
3. series/ data ranges (including position + style)
4. legend (including position + style)

for the following charts:

1. High low close chart
2. open high low close chart
3. volume high low close chart
4. volume open high low close chart
5. box and whisker chart
6. funnel chart
7. paretoline chart
8. region map chart
9. sunburst chart
10. treemap chart
11. waterfall

Comment: This question is too broad to answer. What one can do is getting the XML of the charts. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324851/how-to-change-the-graphical-attributes-of-a-point-in-an-excel-sunburst-chart-thr/52464948#52464948 for an example using sunburst chart. That can be adopted to other charts of type `application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml`. Please ask a more concrete question. What data of what chart you want to get?

Comment: Thanks, @AxelRichter. I have updated my question. The link you posted seems to be something that I can dig into deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your listed charts seems to be of extended chart type which is not available in versions of Office Open XML up to year 2007. But those old versions of Office Open XML is what Apache POI is developed on.

The  extended chart is not a `XSSFChart`. `XSSFChart` is of type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml` while extended chart is of type `application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml`.

But we can using at least parts of apache poi and have to program the `XSSFChartEx` class our own instead the `XSSFChart` then. Unfortunately also a class `XSSFChartExRelation` is needed because such a relation class of course also not exists already.

In `XSSFChartEx` class we can have getters for needed parts as  title, series, legend, axes then. Simplest will be to get the XML of the parts as `XmlObject`.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLRelation;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GetChartExXML {
            
 private static List<XSSFChartEx> getChartExList(XSSFSheet sheet) {
  List<XSSFChartEx> resultList = new ArrayList<XSSFChartEx>();
  try {
   XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
   if (drawing != null) {
    for (POIXMLDocumentPart dpart : drawing.getRelations()) {
     PackagePart ppart = dpart.getPackagePart();
     if ("application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml".equals(ppart.getContentType())) {
      XSSFChartEx xssfChartEx = new XSSFChartEx(ppart);
      String rId = drawing.getRelationId(dpart);
      drawing.addRelation(
       rId, 
       new XSSFChartExRelation(
        "application/vnd.ms-office.chartex+xml",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2014/relationships/chartEx",
        "/xl/charts/chartEx#.xml"),
       xssfChartEx
      );
      resultList.add(xssfChartEx);
     }
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return resultList;
 } 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("ChartExample.xlsx"));
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   System.out.println("Loaded sheet is " + sheet.getSheetName());
   List<XSSFChartEx> chartExList = getChartExList(sheet);
   System.out.println(chartExList);
   for(XSSFChartEx xssfChartEx : chartExList) {
    //System.out.println(xssfChartEx.getChartExXmlObject());
    System.out.println(xssfChartEx.getTitle());
    System.out.println(xssfChartEx.getSeriesCount());
    System.out.println(xssfChartEx.getSeries(0));
    System.out.println(xssfChartEx.getLegend());
    System.out.println(xssfChartEx.getAxesCount());
    System.out.println(xssfChartEx.getAxis(0));
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 private static class XSSFChartEx extends POIXMLDocumentPart {

  private XmlObject chartExXmlObject;

  private XSSFChartEx(PackagePart part) throws Exception {
   super(part);
   chartExXmlObject = XmlObject.Factory.parse(part.getInputStream());
  }

  private XmlObject getChartExXmlObject() {
   return chartExXmlObject;
  }

  private int getSeriesCount() {
   XmlObject[] result = chartExXmlObject.selectPath(
    "declare namespace cx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex' " +
    ".//cx:chart/cx:plotArea/cx:plotAreaRegion/cx:series"
   );
   return result.length;
  }
  
  private XmlObject getSeries(int number) {
   XmlObject[] result = chartExXmlObject.selectPath(
    "declare namespace cx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex' " +
    ".//cx:chart/cx:plotArea/cx:plotAreaRegion/cx:series"
   );
   if (result.length > number) return result[number];
   return null;
  }

  private int getAxesCount() {
   XmlObject[] result = chartExXmlObject.selectPath(
    "declare namespace cx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex' " +
    ".//cx:chart/cx:plotArea/cx:axis"
   );
   return result.length;
  }
  
  private XmlObject getAxis(int number) {
   XmlObject[] result = chartExXmlObject.selectPath(
    "declare namespace cx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex' " +
    ".//cx:chart/cx:plotArea/cx:axis"
   );
   if (result.length > number) return result[number];
   return null;
  }

  private XmlObject getTitle() {
   XmlObject[] result = chartExXmlObject.selectPath(
    "declare namespace cx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex' " +
    ".//cx:chart/cx:title"
   );
   if (result.length > 0) return result[0];
   return null;
  }
  
  private XmlObject getLegend() {
   XmlObject[] result = chartExXmlObject.selectPath(
    "declare namespace cx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex' " +
    ".//cx:chart/cx:legend"
   );
   if (result.length > 0) return result[0];
   return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void commit() throws IOException {
   PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
   OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
   chartExXmlObject.save(out);
   out.close();
  }
 }

 private static class XSSFChartExRelation extends POIXMLRelation {
  private XSSFChartExRelation(String type, String rel, String defaultName) {
   super(type, rel, defaultName);
  }
 }
}
```

The real challenge is to find out the meaning of the found XML. Fortunately most of the XML element names are  self-explanatory. So one should be able to find out where is the title text for example. But to get the meaning of series settings, legend settings and axes settings can be challenging.

Comment: I've added some changes to poi-ooxml-full using https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66650 - should be in the POI 5.2.4 release - it's only partial support but it should make working with chartEx data a little easier.